# Flutter Google Map Crashes On Navigation To Another Page

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am using
google_maps_flutter: ^2.3.1 (https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

This is my map page
[map_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpPli.png)

The Edit icon has this onPressed code
`onPressed: () { Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/edit-visits'); },`

Flutter error:

```
[        ] Lost connection to device.

[   +1 ms] DevFS: Deleting filesystem on the device (file:///Users/plego/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/94901D34-C92B-42B9-A9AD-0B98E1F74F42/data/Containers/Data/Application/BCA77063-70EB-4CD2-A470-92498CAC0797/tmp/ameripro_app_may19UDSnvp/ameripro_app_may19/)

[   +5 ms] executing: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl terminate 94901D34-C92B-42B9-A9AD-0B98E1F74F42 com.plego.ameripro
```

Xcode error:
[xcode_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7oSk.png)

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      GMSServices.setMetalRendererEnabled(true)
      GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YES MY KEY")
   
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I have spent several hours and unable to solve the issue. The App is working great on all Android devices and emulator but Crashes on all iOS emulator and devices ONLY on navigation to another page from Google Maps.

I have tried various suggestions from internet but didn't find any solution for stoping the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to get more info about the error and resolve it:

1. Ensure that you have a valid Google Maps API key and that it is correctly set in the `AppDelegate.swift` file. Make sure the API key is enabled for both Android and iOS platforms in the Google Cloud Console.
2. If you are testing on the iOS Simulator, ensure that the simulator has Google Play Maps SDK and it is version compatible with the `google_maps_flutter` package you are using.
3. Open Xcode and go to `Window` > `Devices and Simulators`. Select your simulator or connected iOS device from the list and click on the `View Device Logs` button. This will open the device logs, which may provide additional information about the crash or error. [Example](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/obtain-ios-device-logs-using-mac-and-windows/#:%7E:text=Using%20Xcode,-First%2C%20install%20Xcode&text=Mac%20through%20USB.-,Launch%20Xcode.,left%20side%20of%20the%20screen.)
4. Also, can you check if you are getting no issues when you run `flutter doctor` command.

Hope it helps! Keep Fluttering!

Comment: I followed all of your suggestions.

1. API key is enabled for both Android and iOS. The app is working perfectly on maps.

2. I didnt see Google Play Services on any iOS device and emulator and not on Apple Store.

3. There is no Open Console button. Here is list https://files.fm/f/vh9ekkqgn

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it helps you out now. Another thing that is obvious but just for confirmation just make sure the API is added correctly. Typically your Xcode error indicates a crash caused by accessing an invalid or deallocated memory address.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).